# New google cloud instance not showing allocated disk space, and how to mount second disk?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I created a new instance with 100GB of disk space, but df output shows a small fraction of this.  I also configured it to attach a second, 800GB disk, but cant find how to mount it.  Help?

Here's the disk options from the instance on the UI:

[image: UI disk options]

And here's what I see on the command line once the instance boots:

[image]

Comment: This question would be a good fit for the unix and linux stack exchange, but since it does not concern programming, it is not appropriate for SO.